# Get all the children from xml tag using ElementTree

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I am trying to parse XML file using ElementTree and at some point I am getting only first child instead of all the children inside the tag- Following is my XML structure:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <sentences>
        <sentence id="2339">
            <text>I charge it at night and skip taking the cord with me because of the good battery life.</text>
            <aspectTerms>
                <aspectTerm term="cord" polarity="neutral" from="41" to="45"/>
                <aspectTerm term="battery life" polarity="positive" from="74" to="86"/>
            </aspectTerms>
        </sentence>
        <sentence id="812">
            <text>I bought a HP Pavilion DV4-1222nr laptop and have had so many problems with the computer.</text>
        </sentence>
        <sentence id="1316">
            <text>The tech guy then said the service center does not do 1-to-1 exchange and I have to direct my concern to the "sales" team, which is the retail shop which I bought my netbook from.</text>
            <aspectTerms>
                <aspectTerm term="service center" polarity="negative" from="27" to="41"/>
                <aspectTerm term="&quot;sales&quot; team" polarity="negative" from="109" to="121"/>
                <aspectTerm term="tech guy" polarity="neutral" from="4" to="12"/>
            </aspectTerms>
        </sentence>
    </sentences>
```

I want to get 'term' in every 'aspectTerm' tag. Following is my code for that:-

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    tree = ET.parse('Laptops_Train.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    def getAspect(sentences):
        reviewList = []
        text = sentence.find('text').text
        reviewList.append(text)
        for aspectTerms in sentence.iter('aspectTerms'):
            #for aspectTerm in aspectTerms.iter('aspectTerm'): 
            aspect = aspectTerms.find('aspectTerm').get('term')
            print(aspect)
            return aspect

    aspectList = []
    for sentences in root.iter('sentences'):
        for sentence in sentences.iter('sentence'):
            aspectList.append(getAspect(sentence))
```

Actual Results:

```
cord
class 'NoneType'
service center
```

Expected Result:

```
[cord, battery life]
[]
[service center,&quot;sales&quot; team, tech guy]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much easier to do using the lxml library, which has xpath.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.parse('Laptops_Train.xml')
>>> for aspectTerms in tree.xpath('.//aspectTerms'):
...     aspectTerms.xpath('aspectTerm/@term')
... 
['cord', 'battery life']
['service center', '"sales" team', 'tech guy']
```

Notice too that all `aspectTerms` have a `Term` property; there are no empty ones that would give rise to `None`.

**Edit, inspired by comment.**

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.parse('Laptops_Train.xml')
>>> for sentence in tree.xpath('.//sentence'):
...     sentence.xpath('.//aspectTerm/@term')
... 
['cord', 'battery life']
[]
['service center', '"sales" team', 'tech guy']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Your solution is much easier but I have to insert empty string when there is no aspectTerm tag. But no doubt your way of doing this work is much easier but it doesn't fulfills my requirements

Answer (score 1):

So the solution was to use '.findall' instead of .find. Because '.findall' selects all the children. My solution is as follows:-

```
    def getAspect(sentences):
        aspectList = []
        reviewList = []
        text = sentence.find('text').text
        reviewList.append(text)
        for aspectTerms in sentence.iter('aspectTerms'):
            #for aspectTerm in aspectTerms.iter('aspectTerm'): 
            aspect = aspectTerms.findall('aspectTerm')#.get('term')
            for aspectElem in aspect:
                aspects = aspectElem.get('term')
                aspectList.append(aspects)
                print(aspects)
        return aspectList


    aspectList = []
    for sentences in root.iter('sentences'):
        for sentence in sentences.iter('sentence'):
            aspectList.append(getAspect(sentence))
```